# Code Behind Problems (Adobe Premiere CC Extension)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, code-behind

i am new to this topic so sorry if i am missing some basics.

i want to make a adobe premiere CC extension in Flash Builder 4.6 with Adobe Extension Builder 2.1, and i want to keep the application logic away from the design.

I have read [Flex: How to keep code away from MXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468258/flex-how-to-keep-code-away-from-mxml) and i know how Code Behind pattern works, but i don't know how to do this while creating a Extension.

i started a new Adobe Application Extension Project

**project1Premiere.as**

```
package 
{
import com.adobe.csawlib.premiere.Premiere;
import com.adobe.csxs.types.Extension;
import com.adobe.premiere.*;
import spark.components.TextInput;

//re-declaring txt declared in project1.mxml
public var txt:spark.components.TextInput;  

//Use CSExtension rather than WindowedApplication, as the base application 
//class for extensions.
//This class previously was project1Premiere
public class CSExtension extends Extension 
{
    public static function run():void
    {
        var app:App = Premiere.app;
        //your Premiere code here
        txt.text = "testing...";
    }
}
}
```

**project1.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<csxs:CSExtension xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:csxs="com.adobe.csxs.core.*" applicationComplete="appComplete()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import com.adobe.csxs.core.CSInterface;


        [Bindable]
        private var hostName:String = HostObject.mainExtension;


        public function appComplete():void{
            CSInterface.instance.autoThemeColorChange = true;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup height="100%" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
    <s:Button label="Run PR code" click="project1Premiere.run()" enabled="{hostName.indexOf('premiere') > -1}"/>
    <s:TextInput id="txt"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

and i found this error:

A file found in a source-path can not have more than one externally visible definition. txt;CSExtension project1Premiere.as /project1/src

am i missing some attribute in root of .mxml file to reference the .as ?

Thanks in advance,

Filip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely out of my league trying to answer this but I'd like to give it a shot.
Does changing `public var txt:spark.components.TextInput;`

to

`public var txt:spark.components.TextInput = new spark.components.TextInput;`

change anything?
I read something about only certain common classes not needing to be instantiated with the `new` operator but being able to have properties added dynamically. If the TextInput isn't one of those classes setting it's `.text` property later on without creating an instance might cause the problem. I don't completely understand it but it's not a complete stab in the dark.

Comment: i decide to put my logic into project1.mxml file for now...i will try to separate logic and design in later stages...

thanks anyway